# Отправка данных о действии пользователя на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, php, mysql

Здравствуй, народ!
Подскажите, как можно хранить в базе действия пользователя на сайте (клики, движение мышкой, колесиком и время этих действий и/или времени между этими событиями)

У меня есть сайт, и я хочу каждые (5-10 мин, время сессии) Аяксом отсылать все, что сделал пользователь на сайте, как подготовить, в каком виде отослать на сервер и как хранить?

СПАСИБО!

p/s: гугл-аналитики или вебвизоры не предлагать

Comment: Клики еще куда не шло, но

> движение мышкой, колесиком

ИМХО это бред сивой кобыли...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать массив

```
var myEvents=[];
```

повесить на document обработчики "нужных" событий через addEventListener||attachEvent

```
function(e){myEvents.push(e);}
```

и отправить потом JSON.stringify(myEvents) на сервер

Answer (score 2):

Юзай ВэбВизор от яндекса!

меньше геморроя, больше расслабления получишь.

Не страдай фигней ТС.